# How can one zoom on one video during a BlueJeans video conference?

Tags: windows, video, bluejeans

When more than 1 participant share their video in a BlueJeans video conference, how can one zoom on one video?

In the following screenshot, 2 participants (in addition to me) are sharing their videos: I would like to display the left video ("San Jose, Frankfurt") in a larger format (e.g., full screen mode, or close to it).

[image]

Double-clicking or right-clicking on the video didn't work. I use BlueJeans on Microsoft Windows.

Answer (score 1):

According to the BlueJeans customer support, there is currently no way to one zoom on one video.

There is a layout change icon in the lower left corner only switches between the "main video" mode and the video grid mode: it doesn't allow to zoom on one video of one's choice.